# Whats wrong with this one? C++ Array Pointer

Tags: c++

It says:

> [Error] invalid conversion from 'int*' to 'int' [-fpermissive] on line 9 col 5.

What was asked of me to do:

> Make a program that would accept array of 10 integers and determine the highest and the lowest integers from the set of integers. Use pointer variables for the highest and lowest integer.

what i did:

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    int kre_arr[10];
    int *kre_p;
    for(int k = 0; k<=10; k++)
        {
            kre_p[k] = &kre_arr[k];
        }
    int j,temp;
    cout<<"Enter 10 Integers: ";
    for (*kre_p=0; *kre_p < 10; *kre_p++)
        {
            cin>>kre_arr[*kre_p];
        }  
    for(*kre_p=0;*kre_p<=10;*kre_p++)
        {
            for(j=*kre_p+1;j<=10;j++)
                {   
                    if(kre_arr[*kre_p] > kre_arr[j])
                        {
                            temp = kre_arr[*kre_p];
                            kre_arr[*kre_p] = kre_arr[j];
                            kre_arr[j] = temp;
                        }
                }
        }
    for(*kre_p=0;*kre_p<=9;*kre_p++)
        {
            cout<<endl<<kre_arr[*kre_p];
        }
}
```

code i did before adding pointer i dont seem to understand pointer that much.

```html
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    int kre_arr[10];
    int *kre_p;
    int i,j,temp;
    cout<<"Enter 10 Integers: ";
    for (int i=0; i < 10; i++)
 {
    cin>>kre_arr[i];
 }  
 for(i=0;i<=10;i++)
 {
  for(j=i+1;j<=10;j++)
  { 
    if(kre_arr[i] > kre_arr[j])
    {
      temp = kre_arr[i];
      kre_arr[i] = kre_arr[j];
      kre_arr[j] = temp;
      }
   }
 }
  for(i=0;i<=9;i++)
  {
     cout<<endl<<kre_arr[i];
     }
      }
```

Comment: `kre_p[k]` is an integer, not a pointer. Your code is quite messed up, so it's hard to follow what you want to do - do you want to store your values using a single pointer, or store an array of pointers?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking at what you are asked to do I think you just have to determine the highest and lowest int in the array and point to. You sort the array thats slower.

I think it should look like that:

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    int kre_arr[10];
    int *low;
    int *high;

    cout<<"Enter 10 Integers: ";
    for (int i=0; i < 10; i++)
    {
        cin>>kre_arr[i];
    }

    //determine the lowest
    low=&kre_arr[0];
    for(int i=1;i<10;i++)
    {
       if(kre_arr[i] < *low)
       {
           low=&kre_arr[i];
       }
    }

    //determine the highest
    high=&kre_arr[0];
    for(int i=1;i<10;i++)
    {
       if(kre_arr[i] > *high)
       {
           high=&kre_arr[i];
       }
    }

    cout<<"lowest: "<<*low<<"\nhighest: "<<*high;
}
```

Comment: I never thought of it this way, Thank you. it says determine not do descending order, i misunderstood it, fek my life.

Answer (score 0):

kre_p[k] = &kre_arr[k];

kre_arr is array.

kre_arr[k] is integer.

**&kre_arr[k] is integer address ( similar int*)**

kre_p is pointer.

**kre_p[k] is integer.**

So, as a result, you cannot pass directly int* to int.
I guess you want kre_p+k = &kre_arr[k]

Comment: Without at least fixing the lack of allocation of memory, `kre_p+k = &kre_arr[k]` seems like a bad idea too.

Answer (score 0):

Given the state of your code, I fear for your life... So, for your overal survival, and of course in the hopes that you will learn something:

- Never use 'using namespace std'. It's bad form.
- You are not allocating memory for your array of pointers (kre_p). That will cause your program to crash for sure.
- You don't actually *need* an array of pointers. Your array elements can be conveniently referred to by their offset in the array.
- You are doing what appears to be a bubblesort to find the lowest and highest value. That's incredibly inefficient, and completely unnecessary.

C++ can be such a nice language. It bothers me when teachers seem to think they should be teaching it in a form that's as ugly as possible. Consider:

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <array>
#include <iostream>

int main () {
    std::cout << "Enter 10 Integers: ";

    std::array<int, 10> kre_arr;
    for (auto &Val : kre_arr)
        std::cin >> Val;

    const int Low = *std::min_element (kre_arr.begin (), kre_arr.end ());
    const int High = *std::max_element (kre_arr.begin (), kre_arr.end ());

    // The assignment calls for pointers, so let's not disappoint.

    const int *LowPtr = &Low;
    const int *HighPtr = &High;
}
```

Comment: Lol, i know i suck at at it but ty for the feedback on how i am doing on programming.

Comment: Hey, all meant in good cheer! When I started out I was crap at it. Twenty+ years of trying to get better does make a difference... And anyway, you did mention a threat to your life ;-)